# Unrecognised music format to play mp3 file using SDL

Tags: c, linux, sdl

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_mixer.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
Mix_Music *play_sound = NULL;
void cleanUp();

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{

    int channel;
    int audio_rate;
    Uint16 audio_format;
    int audio_channels;
    int audio_buffers;

        if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO)<0)
        printf("Error In Init");

    audio_rate = 44100;
    audio_format = AUDIO_S16;
    audio_channels = 2;
    audio_buffers = 4096;


    if(Mix_OpenAudio(audio_rate, audio_format, 2, 4096)<0) {
                 //Some error shows here

    } else {
        Mix_QuerySpec(&audio_rate, &audio_format, &audio_channels);
        printf("Opened audio at %d Hz %d bit %s (%s), %d bytes audio buffer\n", audio_rate,
                (audio_format&0xFF),
                (audio_channels > 2) ? "surround" :                         (audio_channels > 1) ? "stereo" : "mono", 
                (audio_format&0x1000) ? "BE" : "LE",
                audio_buffers );
    }

    play_sound = Mix_LoadMUS("1.mp3");

    if ( play_sound == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't load 1.mp3: %s\n",
            SDL_GetError());
        cleanUp();
        return;
    }

        Mix_PlayMusic(play_sound, -1);


    while (Mix_PlayingMusic() || Mix_PausedMusic()) {
            SDL_Delay(100);
        }

        cleanUp();
        return 0;
}

void cleanUp()
{
     Mix_FreeMusic(play_sound);
     Mix_CloseAudio();
     SDL_Quit();
}
```

#### And here is my output:

```
Opened audio at 44100 Hz 16 bit stereo (LE), 4096 bytes audio buffer
Couldn't load 1.mp3: Unrecognised music format
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem to playing mp3 file with `SDL` ?

Comment: You do not call [`Mix_Init`](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer.html#SEC9).

Comment: same problem after putting `Mix_Init`

Comment: With `MIX_INIT_MP3`? Then you might be missing the required mp3 libraries needed. Check the return value of `Mix_Init`.

Comment: yes with `MIX_INIT_MP3` and its returning `0`.

Comment: If you read the documentation, `Mix_Init` should return a bitmask of the currently initialized loaders. Since it returns zero for you, the mp3 loader haven't been initialized, meaning you are missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Here is a small footprint !!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <smpeg/smpeg.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  SDL_Surface * screen;
  SMPEG *mpeg;
  SMPEG_Info info;

  /* Init SDL: */
  
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO |
           SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
  
  mpeg = SMPEG_new("1.mp3",&info, 1);

  SMPEG_play(mpeg);

  do
    {
      SDL_Delay(250);
    }while(!SDL_QuitRequested() && SMPEG_status(mpeg)==SMPEG_PLAYING);
    
  SMPEG_delete(mpeg);
  SDL_Quit();
  
  return(0);
}
```

#### Compile using

```
gcc `sdl-config --cflags --libs` sample.c -o sample -lSDL_mixer -lsmpeg
```

Comment: FYI, i had to add -lSDL to the gcc cmd-line to get it to compile properly. on Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

It supports WAV files by default but you will need SMPEG library along with some more complex lines of code to make mp3's work.  I ran into the same issue few years back and found through various forums that mp3's are tricky.  I ended up converting my files to OGG which worked fairly straight forward.

Comment: but there is an example comes with SDL mixer source named `playmus.c`, it is playing a mp3 file

Comment: It cannot play mp3 standalone.  I am not sure if the source that you got also has all the necessary libraries that enable mp3 playback.  Check this out for complete details on how mp3's can be handled using sdlmixer:  https://github.com/ps2dev/ps2sdk-ports/tree/master/sdlmixer/src